# struggling with derivative of natural log of sin x

Tags: calculus

I was hoping someone could help me understand my struggle to derive the $y(x) = \ln (\sin x)$

My two assumptions

- the derivative of $\ln(g(x)) = \frac{g(x)'}{g(x)}$.
- And deriving the original equation $\ln(\sin(x))$ will require an application of the chain rule.

So if:

$$g(x) = \sin(x)$$

Then the derivative using the chain rule would be:

$$y(x)' = \frac{g(x)'}{g(x)} g(x)'$$

Thus I thought the solution would be the following:

$$y(x)' = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\cos(x) = \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)} = \cos(x)\cot(x)$$

But the reported answer (for the online course I'm following) is:

$$y(x)' = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}\cos(x) = \cot(x)$$

So I'm pretty close, but it seems to be the $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ that is alluding me. I thought this would be $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ $\left(\text{the result of } \frac{g(x)'}{g(x)}\right)$ but I'm clearly missing something.

Any advice for an amateur but enthusiastic learner is much appreciated.

Comment: In the rule $(\ln(g(x)))' = \frac{g'} {g}$ the chain rule is already used. So your idea is a double use of it. The answer is $y'= \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ therefore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain rule is already taken into account in $g^\prime/g$, so you don't need a second $g^\prime$ factor. The correct result is $\cot x$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac d {dx} \ln x & = \frac 1 x \\[10pt]
\frac d {dx} \ln g(x) & = \big(\ln'g(x)\big)\cdot g'(x) = \frac 1 {g(x)} \cdot g'(x) \\[10pt]
\frac d {dx} \ln \sin x & = \big(\ln'\sin x\big)\cdot \sin'(x) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {\sin x} \cdot \cos x.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Look the difference :
Assume that
$$y(x)=\ln(g(h(x)))=\ln(G(x))$$

then

$$y'(x)=\frac{g'(h(x))}{g(h(x))}h'(x)$$

In your case $ h(x)=x$ and $ h'(x)=1$.

For example, if $$y(x)=\ln(\sin(3x))$$
then
$$y'(x)=3\frac{\cos(3x)}{\sin(3x)}$$

You have also
$$y'(x)=\frac{G'(x)}{G(x)}$$